# Ubuntu 20.4 LTS server install ends with kernel panic

Tags: system-installation

I've been trying to install ubuntu server from a fresh ISO and a USB drive that I know works (has been used to install ubuntu on other machines). When I boot from the USB drive, I get the purple screen with a few icons at the bottom, followed by a kernel panic message. I have attatched the output below. Can anyone help with this?

Kernel panic message:

[image: screen photo]

Comment: Did you write a new ISO to the USB stick? Maybe something went wrong with the write process? Try the USB stick in another machine to check.

Comment: As I explicitly explained above, I have already tried the USB stick in other machines and have downloaded the newest ISO

Comment: You did NOT specify whether you tried the USB in another machine AFTER writing the "fresh ISO" to it or not.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have tried the USB with the fresh ISO in another machine and it works

Comment: Does the computer have an Nvidia graphics card? Is there an option to boot with a safe graphics driver or similar? Did you try that? Did you try booting with the USB drive in other USB ports?

Comment: I have tried with the USB drive in other ports and I can't see any obvious way to boot with a diffifferent graphics driver. I think this now goes beyond a problem with installing ubuntu alone, as I can't boot from my kali linux live usb either and get the same kernel panic error message. Any help would still be really appreciated though :)